# How to deal with ts function with two possible return types

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a function that returns a resolved promise with a boolean, but there is a slight chance that it will reject the promise and if it does, I need it to return an error object.

```
export async function someFunc(): Promise<boolean> {
  return await socket
    .send(something)
    .then(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(boolean);
    })
    .catch((error: ISocketError) => {
      return Promise.reject(errorObject);
    });
}
```

Besides declaring the function return type as `Promise<boolean | ISocketError>`, (which would cause me to have to declare the variable I'm saving this to as the same type), is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Bravo.. just like the name @Bravo

Comment: Please don't silently fix your code after somebody points out obvious issues. Post a comment that you accidentally posted an old version or whatever else you think you need to save face.

Comment: "is there a way around this issue?" What is the issue? Do you don't want to use `ISockerError` and only want to use `boolean`?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put the return statement there.

Comment: @nem035 yes that is correct.

Comment: You can not `catch` inside that function and handle exceptions somewhere higher up the call stack?

Comment: @Bravo Exactly, and it tells OP what we can see their edits.

Comment: `Promise.reject(errorObject)`   Is not actually a return,  if you did want to return an error object, then you would do `Promise.resolve(errorObject)`.